# How to Sort WPF MultiBinding DataGridTextColumn based on the MultiBinding?

Tags: wpf, sorting, wpfdatagrid, multibinding, datagridtextcolumn

I want to Sort the DataGridTextColumn based on the Multibinding Values - The Text Column is bind with both Date and Time, so the sorting operation should be done based on **DateTime**.

The XMAL Source Code is

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Visit Date" CanUserSort="True" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.SortMemberPath>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="VisitDate"/>
            <Binding Path="VisitTime" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.SortMemberPath>
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="VisitDate"/>
            <Binding Path="VisitTime" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The View and View Model C# Source Code is

```
public class Employee
{
    public string empName { get; set; }
    public string VisitDate { get; set; }
    public string VisitTime { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }

    public EmployeeInfo()
    {
        EmployeeList = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee { empName = "John", VisitDate = "11/28/2015", VisitTime = "05:12 PM" });
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee { empName = "Potter", VisitDate = "10/28/2015", VisitTime = "04:33 PM" });
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee { empName = "James", VisitDate = "11/27/2015", VisitTime = "09:12 AM" });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should create a custom comparer and apply it to the datagrid. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129601/how-can-i-apply-a-custom-sort-rule-to-a-wpf-datagrid

Comment: Can't you provide a viewmodel property that contains the formatted result text and bind to it instead of multibinding in the view?

Comment: Kindly refer the ViewModel.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan So, how about adding `public string VisitDateTime { get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", VisitDate, VisitTime); } }` to your `Employee` and bind to it *instead* of the multibinding? This doesn't answer your question of how to sort by multibinding but it should solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan maybe you want to sort by the actual date and time instead of their string representation. If thats this case I may write an answer based on my suggestion - but still as a viewmodel solution rather than binding related.

Comment: Another thought: Why do you keep your date and time as string instead of `DateTime` or `Nullable<DateTime>`? You could have all the information including sortability in a single property and just access the portion that you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. But I need the solution for the above mentioned class without adding one more property. My main project contains lots of implementation, so, I can't able to create an additional property as said like you.

Comment: If you can't do this little tweak (thats not breaking any existing code) then maybe you can go with an attached property similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651624/sorting-on-datagrid-column-with-binded-data-and-converter

Comment: My Model is in Remote Server. I Can't able to add an additional property. I should use the property whatever the is there.

I visited the URL, but in the solution they are not followed the MVVM approach.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan Sorting is a view property, so using the attached property approach with code in the view to accomplish sorting is a perfectly valid way to solve this. It does not violate the MVVM pattern and it allows to leave your ViewModel untouched.