# How to Implement Converter in DataGridTextColumn SortMemberPath?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, wpfdatagrid

I wish to Sort the Column based on the value returning by the Converter. I'm having a class it contains two property VisitDate and VisitTime, but I'm having only one column for Visit Info in the XAML to display Visit Date and Time. So, I created one Converter for merging VisitDate and VisitTime, it displays the value as I preferred, but I can't able to sort the column.

My XAML Source Code

```
<DataGrid Name="grdPendingList" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ui:DateTimeMergingConverter x:Key="DateTimeMergingConverterKey"></ui:DateTimeMergingConverter>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee" Binding="{Binding empName}" CanUserSort="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Visit Info" Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DateTimeMergingConverterKey}}" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DateTimeMergingConverterKey}}"/>
</DataGrid>
```

The Model and View Model Class Source Code is

```
public class Employee
{
    public string empName { get; set; }
    public string VisitDate { get; set; }
    public string VisitTime { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeInfo
{
    ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeList = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
    public EmployeeInfo()
    {
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee { empName = "John", VisitDate = "11/28/2015", VisitTime = "05:12 PM" });
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee { empName = "Potter", VisitDate = "10/28/2015", VisitTime = "04:33 PM" });
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee { empName = "James", VisitDate = "11/27/2015", VisitTime = "09:12 AM" });
    }
}
```

The Converter Source Code is

```
public class DateTimeMergingConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                Employee pData = value as Employee;
                string dateStr = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pData.VisitDate) ? string.Empty : ((pData.VisitDate).Split('/')).Count() > 2 ? pData.VisitDate : pData.VisitDate + "/2015").ToString() + " " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pData.VisitTime) ? string.Empty : (pData.VisitTime)).ToString();
                DateTime dt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateStr.Trim()) ? DateTime.Now : DateTime.Parse(dateStr);
                return dt;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object o, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't just create a Property VisitInfo in your Employee Object that provides the full information ?

```
public class Employee
{
    public string empName { get; set; }
    public string VisitDate { get; set; }
    public string VisitTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime VisitInfo
    {
        get { //Do your stuff here }
        set { //Do your stuff here }
    }
}

public class EmployeeInfo
{
    ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeList = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
    public EmployeeInfo()
    {
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee { empName = "John", VisitDate = "11/28/2015", VisitTime = "05:12 PM" });
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee { empName = "Potter", VisitDate = "10/28/2015", VisitTime = "04:33 PM" });
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee { empName = "James", VisitDate = "11/27/2015", VisitTime = "09:12 AM" });
    }
}
```

And then you will bind VisitInfo in your xaml :

```
<DataGrid Name="grdPendingList" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}">
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee" Binding="{Binding empName}" CanUserSort="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Visit Info" Binding="{Binding VisitInfo}" CanUserSort="True"/>
</DataGrid>
```

It's more simple and avoid you to reduce the use of Converters. Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. But I need the solution for the above mentioned class without adding one more property. My main project contains lots of implementation, so, I can't able to create an additional property VisitInfo.

Comment: Unfortunetly no, you can't bind to a ConverterParameter. There's two options I've used in the past: instead of using a Converter, create a property on your ViewModel (or whatever you're binding to) which does the conversion for you. If you still want to go the Converter route, pass the entire bound object to the converter and then you can do your calculation that way.

Comment: can you please try : Binding="{Binding Path=. , Converter={StaticResource DateTimeMergingConverterKey}}" and also SortMemberPath="{Binding Path=. , Converter={StaticResource DateTimeMergingConverterKey}}"

Comment: I tried by this method but I can't able to achieve the Sorting operation. Kindly refer the XAML Source code I have pasted in my Question.

Comment: I hope this will help you then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651624/sorting-on-datagrid-column-with-binded-data-and-converter Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to sort by calculated data but do not have an access (or ability) to change the structure of the data you may consider one of the following methods:

1. Extending the class locally on your app with an extra property which will be used for SortMemberPath
2. Handle the DataGrid's "Sorting" event to sort your collection manually (by your custom calculation) if the right column is clicked for sort.